# Generics in C# with "as" and "is" having troubles, "is" check fails

Tags: c#, generics

I'm running into troubles with C# generics:

MappingAdapter is a common abstract base class that FullMappingAdapter and LiteMappingAdapter inherit from / implement.

Creating an instance of my generic class session:

```
session = new Session<FullMappingAdapter>(
// ...
)
```

In session, deciding what kind of session we are:

```
// class declaration:
public class Session<T> :  ISession
                           where T : MappingAdapter {
    // ...
    // method body:
    T t = null;
    if (t is FullMappingAdapter) {
        // need parameter, cannot use where T : new() above
        t = new FullMappingAdapter(someData) as T;
    } else if (t is LiteMappingAdapter) {
        t = new LiteMappingAdapter(someData) as T;
    } else {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown Adapter specified, please fix.");
    }

    // ... more methods here ...        

}
```

I always get NotSupportedException thrown. Also, when looking at my stack in the debugger it says "FullMappingAdapter" in the "type" column of t, which is correct, and what I expected. But why doesn't the "is" keyword also recognize the type?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: t is set to null, so how will 'as' work?

Comment: I'm coming from C++ and just because you set a pointer to an instance of a class to NULL doesn't change the type of that pointer. It's still of type "pointer to class xyz". I was assuming C# also maintains type information, even though an object reference isnt bound to an actual instance yet. Thought that was a valid assumption, but I guess things work differently in C#, thanks for the insights!

Comment: C# generics is not same as C++ templates, the reason it will work in C++ is because C++ templates are compiled to new classes which guards type cast system. In C#, generic class is always generic and type is just another variable guarding type casting, so C# generics does everything in runtime, so C# has no way to compare null to anything. Where else in C++ even though something is null, compiler knows its type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`null` is never anything.

You want to check `typeof(T)` for being exact type (or maybe [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)) instead.

Exact match (not the same as `is FullMappingAdapter` because it will not include derived types)

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(FullMappingAdapter))
```

Assignable - same as `is FullMappingAdapter`:

```
if (typeof(FullMappingAdapter).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

Comment: thank you very much I thought "is" could still check the type of a generic parameter..

Comment: @Tom - `is` can be used in generic methods just fine with the same limitation as everywhere - as long as value is not `null` you can check if type matches.

Answer (score 3):

You should modify your check to use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(FullMappingAdapter))
```

and so on

Comment: +1: note that it is slightly different from `is FullMappingAdapter` because it will not include derived types.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check like this

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(FullMappingAdapter))
```